# Pentaho CSV input error, dont know how to solve it

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

```
We failed to initialize at least one step.  Execution can not begin!
2021/01/18 15:31:45 - Carte - Installing timer to purge stale objects after 1440 minutes.
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - /Transformation 1 - Dispatching started for transformation [/Transformation 1]
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [CSV file input]
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.csvinput.CsvInput.init(CsvInput.java:875)
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.StepInitThread.run(StepInitThread.java:69)
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - CSV file input.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2021/01/18 15:33:05 - /Transformation 1 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Step [CSV file input.0] failed to initialize!
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" - your job is failing due to issue with data or the data-type which you have specified.
Correct the specific record where job is failing.

Comment: actually i was able to run the transformation previously with the same data. i downgraded the version and it worked.